# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout in Android, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2, android-databinding

I have implemented RecyclerView in my app with **Kotlin** using **Refrofit, MVVM, DataBinding, Coroutines**. The same code works fine in another fragment but not here.
*Note: The retrofit functions returns the commentsList successfully but only problem in displaying the list in a recyclerView.

```
  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    val api = ApiRepository()
    factory = CommentsViewModelFactory(api)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(CommentsViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getComments(requireActivity())
    viewModel.commentsList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { comments ->
        rvComment.also {
            it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            it.setHasFixedSize(true)
            if (comments != null) {
                it.adapter = HomeServicesCommentsAdapter(comments, this)
            } 
        }

    })
}
```

The ViewModel looks like this, i declared the comments as MutableLiveData, which returns the data successfully but the only issue is with the adapter attachment.

```
class CommentsViewModel(private val repository: ApiRepository) : ViewModel() {
var userComment: String? = null

private val comments = MutableLiveData<List<Comment>>()
private lateinit var job: Job

val commentsList: MutableLiveData<List<Comment>>
    get() = comments

fun getComments(context: Context) {
    job = CoroutinesIO.ioThenMain(
        {
            repository.getServices(context)
        }, {
            for (i in it!!.data.data)
                comments.value = i.comments
        }


    )
}
```

Here is the adapter implementation

```
class HomeServicesCommentsAdapter(
    private val comments: List<Comment>,
    private val listenerService: RvListenerServiceComments
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeServicesCommentsAdapter.ServicesViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = comments.size


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        ServicesViewHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.custom_comment_layout,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServicesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.recyclerViewServicesBinding.comments = comments[position]
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ServicesViewHolder(
        val recyclerViewServicesBinding: CustomCommentLayoutBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(recyclerViewServicesBinding.root)

}
```

Let me know if you need the xml layout files.

Comment: Attach the adapter when your view is getting created. When you get the data submit the data to the adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: @ArpanSarkar that's not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving layout manager at runtime while observing data ,
Define layoutmanager inside xml

eg:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvNews"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_your_layout"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Remove below lines from observer

```
it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
```

**EDIT:**
Do not create instance of adapter while observing data because observing data is not on  MainThread So make sure you set data on `MainThread`

```
val adapter = HomeServicesCommentsAdapter(arrayListOf(), this)
        rvComment?.adapter = adapter
        viewModel.getComments(requireActivity())
        viewModel.commentsList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { comments ->
                    comments?.let{adapter.setData(comments)}//define setData(list:ArrayList<Comments>) method in your adapter 
               
        })
```

HomeServicesCommentsAdapter.kt:

```
........
private var mObjects: MutableList<Comment>? = ArrayList()// top level declaration

fun setData(objects: List<Comment>?) {
        this.mObjects = objects as MutableList<Comment>
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
......
```

Comment: its not working, caught: E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout

Comment: Can you please explain this function a little, what to do of that comments in setData function: 
    fun setData(comments: List<Comment>) {

    }

Comment: In your `HomeServicesCommentsAdapter` create fun called `setData(item:List<Coment>)` It will set data to in HomeServicesCommentsAdapter  as soon as it observe it

Comment: The setData function in adapter gets the list values but not setting up in textViews, as i attached through data binding.

Comment: Assign the comments into mObjects i,e inside `init{ mObjects = comments }` and `getItemCount() = mObjects.size`

Comment: Not working...did what you mentioned but same results...

Comment: the issue been resolved but there is a bug now: showing only last item comments...i.e i have a nested array of comments so the current implementation only picks the last item comments array.

Comment: Brother there might be viewHolder or dataModel issue not sure but your `mObject` should contain all the data provided to adapter at the time of binding get `holder.recyclerViewServicesBinding.comments = mObjects[position]`

Comment: yes that line is already there. Thank you very much for your time.